# xPath in JavaScript doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

so I try to figure out my problem with xPath. I'm totaly new in this, so I thought you could help me (in JavaScript).

I got this simple html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LOL</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>


    </body>
</html>
```

And I want to alert "hello" from h1. I wrote something like this:

```
var xPath = document.evaluate("//h1", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);

alert(xPath);
```

But it doesn't work, it's not alerting and doesn't return any value. Did I miss something?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you running this in a browser? If so are you getting an error in the console window of the inspector?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not mandatory to use `XPath`, you can try:

```
var message = document.querySelector("h1").textContent;
alert(message);
```

If you still want to use `XPath`:

```
var xPath = document.evaluate("//h1", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
element = xPath.iterateNext();
alert(element.textContent);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I have to use xPath.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should've alerted something, and with a little modification (notice the `.stringValue`) it should alert 'Hello' as expected :

```js
var xPath = document.evaluate("//h1", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
alert(xPath.stringValue);
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

Different story if your actual HTML has a default namespace (XHTML maybe). To verify that this is the case try and see if the following XPath, which ignores namespaces, works :

```
//*[local-name()='h1']
```